# Split String in PySpark Dataframe

Tags: python, json, split, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to split a column in a PySpark dataframe, the column (string type) looks like the following:

```
[{"quantity":25,"type":"coins","balance":35}]
[{"balance":40,"type":"coins","quantity":25}]
[{"quantity":2,"type":"column_breaker","balance":2},{"quantity":2,"type":"row_breaker","balance":2},{"quantity":2,"type":"single_block_breaker","balance":2},{"quantity":1,"type":"rainbow","balance":1},{"quantity":135,"type":"coins","balance":140}]
```

So some of them have a set of `"quantity, type, balance"`, while some of them have multiple such entries. I tried to treat it as a JSON variable and split:

```
schema = StructType(
[
    StructField('balance', StringType(), True),
    StructField('type', StringType(), True),
    StructField('quantity', StringType(), True)
 ]
 )

temp = merger.withColumn("data", 
from_json("items",schema)).select("items", col('data.*'))
display(temp)
```

But it could only split the observations with one set. I would like an output like

```
balance|quantity|type
   35  |   25   |coins
   40  |   25   |coins
.......
```

such that the observations with one set split to one observation and the observations with multiple sets split to multiple observations with a vertical placement.

In addition, after splitting into multiple rows, how can I identify each observation? Say, I have another variable with is the ID, how can I assign ID back?

Comment: could you share the desired result ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple JSONs with each row you can use the trick to replace comma between objects to newline and the split by newline using the `explode` function. So for DF like this:

```
>>> df.show()
+-----------------+
|            items|
+-----------------+
|         {"a": 1}|
|{"a": 2},{"a": 3}|
+-----------------+
```

this code does the job:

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, StringType
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, explode
>>> split_jsons = lambda jsons: jsons.replace('},{', '}\n{').split('\n')
>>> df.withColumn('one_json_per_row', udf(split_jsons, ArrayType(StringType()))('items')) \
...    .select(explode('one_json_per_row').alias('item')).show()
+--------+
|    item|
+--------+
|{"a": 1}|
|{"a": 2}|
|{"a": 3}|
+--------+
```

Then you can use the regular code

Comment: thanks a lot for the comments. I got an error which said:  
   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 47911.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 47911.0 (TID 4961002, 10.45.197.163, executor 1993): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):

Answer (score 0):

You can use json library and use rdd.flatMap() to parse and breakup json string array into multiple rows

```
import json

data = [("[{\"quantity\":25,\"type\":\"coins\",\"balance\":35}]",),
         ("[{\"balance\":40,\"type\":\"coins\",\"quantity\":25}]",),
    ("[{\"quantity\":2,\"type\":\"column_breaker\",\"balance\":2},{\"quantity\":2,\"type\":\"row_breaker\",\"balance\":2},{\"quantity\":2,\"type\":\"single_block_breaker\",\"balance\":2},{\"quantity\":1,\"type\":\"rainbow\",\"balance\":1},{\"quantity\":135,\"type\":\"coins\",\"balance\":140}]",)]

schema = StructType([StructField("items", StringType(), True)])
df = spark.createDataFrame(data,schema)

def transformRow(row):
    jsonObj = json.loads(row[0])
    rows = [Row(**item) for item in jsonObj]
    return rows

df.rdd.flatMap(transformRow).toDF().show()
```

output

```
+-------+--------+--------------------+
|balance|quantity|                type|
+-------+--------+--------------------+
|     35|      25|               coins|
|     40|      25|               coins|
|      2|       2|      column_breaker|
|      2|       2|         row_breaker|
|      2|       2|single_block_breaker|
|      1|       1|             rainbow|
|    140|     135|               coins|
+-------+--------+--------------------+
```